# Hensel's lemma question

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find a root$\bmod{3^4}$of the polynomial $f (x) = x^4 + 10x^2 + x + 3$.

I tried to successively derive the polynomial and study the congruences at $f (x) = 0,$ but I got nowhere. Is it the right way?

Comment: Apply the algorithm in the proof of hensel's lemma

Comment: @gmn_1450:  did you mean *Hensel*?

Comment: For the simplest form of Hensel's lemma you need to find some $a$ such that $f(a) \equiv 0 \mod 3$ and $f'(a) \not \equiv 0 \mod 3$ in order to satisfy the requirement to have a root to lift up $\mod 3^4$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First solve $x^4+10x^2+x+3\equiv0\bmod3$.

$x^4+x^2+x\equiv0\bmod3$

$x(x^3+x+1)\equiv0\bmod3$

$x(x-1)(x^2+x+2)\equiv0\bmod3$.

Solutions are $x\equiv0,1\bmod3$.

Now solve $x^4+10x^2+x+3\equiv0\bmod 9$.  $x=3k+0$ or $1$.

With $x=3k,$ it's $(3k)^4+(3k)^2+3k+3\equiv0\bmod9$

or $3k+3\equiv0\bmod9$ or $k+1\equiv0\bmod3$ or $k\equiv2\bmod3.$

With $x=3k+1$, it's $(3k+1)^4+(3k+1)^2+3k+1+3\equiv0\bmod9$

or $12k+1+6k+1+3k+3\equiv0\bmod9$ or $21k+6\equiv0\bmod9$ or

$7k+2\equiv0\bmod3$ or $k\equiv1\bmod3$.

Solutions are $x\equiv6,4\bmod9$.

Now solve $x^4+10x^2+x+3\equiv0\bmod27$.  $x=9n+4$ or $6$.

With $x=9n+4$, it's $(9n+4)^4+10(9n+4)^2+9n+4+3\equiv0\bmod27$

or $4\cdot9n\cdot4^3+4^4+10\cdot72n+160+9n+7\equiv0\mod27$ or $3033n+423\equiv0\bmod27$

or $337n+47\equiv0\bmod3$ or $n+2\equiv0\bmod3$ or $n\equiv1\bmod3$.

With $x=9n+6$, it's $(9n+6)^4+10(9n+6)^2+9n+6+3\equiv0\bmod27$

or $4\cdot9n\cdot6^3+6^4+1080n+360+9n+9\equiv0\bmod27$ or $8865n+1665\equiv0\bmod27$

or $985n+185\equiv0\bmod3$ or $n+2\equiv0\bmod3$ or $n\equiv1\bmod3$.

Solutions are $x\equiv13, 15\bmod 27$.

The solutions mod $27$ can then be lifted to solutions mod $81$,

and that is left as an exercise for the reader.